# Is it possible to prevent SSL stripping attack via DNSSEC or IPSEC?

Tags: tls, attacks, ipsec, dnssec, sslstrip

I am pondering about SSL Stripping attack. But is there any way to prevent this attack by DNSSEC or IPSEC?

Answer (score 1):

DNSSec does only prevent SSL stripping if the man in the middle attack needed for the SSL stripping attack was done using DNS spoofing. If done the more common ways like ARP spoofing or DHCP spoofing or similar it does not prevent SSL stripping.

Similar IPSec does not prevent SSL stripping if the attacker is inside the same with IPSec protected network, i.e. using a system which is part of the network. It will only prevent SSL stripping if the attacker is not part of the IPSec network and only can see the already encrypted (with IPSec) traffic.

Comment: In the future something like DNSSEC/DANE could prevent the attack by telling browsers to require SSL.

Comment: @immibis this is already today with the HSTS preload list: https://hstspreload.org/

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yes and it's a pretty terrible solution.